# Problema ao fazer request com ajax no Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, laravel-5.4

Estou aprendendo a linguagem web para a criação do meu site e utilizando o framework Laravel 5.4, e tendo problemas com envio de formulários com ajax.

Todo formulário que eu envio, me retorna o erro:

> Unprocessable Entity{"account":["The account field is required."]}

quando existem regras configuradas no FormRequest. Li em diversos locais e alguns diziam que era porque não estava sendo enviando em json, então procurei saber como fazer isso e tentei fazer, mas ainda assim continua. Removi as regras e dei um var_dump no resultado e está me retornando:

> OKarray(0) { }

Não faço ideia de onde esteja saindo esse "OK" e nem o motivo dos inputs não estarem sendo enviados.
Meu conteudo:

***register.blade.php***

```
@section('content')
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
                <h3 class="widget-title" style="border-color: #34495e"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> @lang('page.register.title')</h3>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="wcontainer">
                <div class="formcontainer">
                    <form id="register" name="register" method="post" action="" onsubmit="$('#regresult').ajaxLoader('post', 'register', '#register'); return false;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border: 0">
                            <tr style="background: none">
                                <td width="50%" align="left">
                                    <strong>@lang('page.register.account')</strong>
                                    <input id="account" name="account" type="text" maxlength="10" tabindex="1" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="50%" align="right">
                                    <strong>@lang('page.register.pid')</strong>
                                    <input id="pid" name="pid" type="text" maxlength="7" tabindex="2" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background: none">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <strong>@lang('page.register.password')</strong>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" type="text" maxlength="10" tabindex="3" />
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>@lang('page.register.rpassword')</strong>
                                    <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" type="text" maxlength="10" tabindex="4" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background: none">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <strong>@lang('page.register.mail')</strong>
                                    <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text" maxlength="30" tabindex="5" />
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>@lang('page.register.rmail')</strong>
                                    <input id="mail_confirmation" name="mail_confirmation" type="text" maxlength="30" tabindex="6" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background: none">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" style="width: 302px; margin: 0 auto" data-sitekey="{{ config('recaptcha.public_key') }}" data-tabindex="7"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <input id="agree" name="agree" type="checkbox" tabindex="8" value="1" /> @lang('page.register.agree')<br />
                                    <input id="subscriber" name="subscriber" type="checkbox" tabindex="9" value="1" /> @lang('page.register.subscriber')
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background: none">
                                <td colspan="2" align="center" width="100%" style="text-align: center">
                                    <button type="submit" style="width: 35%; margin: 0 auto;" tabindex="10">@lang('page.register.button')</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="regresult">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
@stop
```

***RegisterRequest.php***

```
...

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        ];
    }
}
```

***RegisterController.php***

```
...

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('page.register')
                ->renderSections()['content'];
    }

    public function store(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->all());
    }
}
```

***web.php***

```
// register
Route::get('register', 'Page\RegisterController@create');
Route::post('register', 'Page\RegisterController@store');
```

***ajax.js***

```
$.fn.extend({
    ajaxLoader: function(type, url, form) {
        var self = $(this);
        var data = '';

        if (form !== undefined) {
            data = $(form).serialize();
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                self.html('<div id="loading"></div>');
            },
            success: function(result) {
                self.html(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                self.html(result.statusText + result.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Eu estou há horas tentando fazer isso funcionar e não tive se quer, um processo positivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getulio,

Não estou familiarizado com Laravel, mas acredito que o problema seja no request. Você definiu:

`dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Mas no `data` vc usou serialize do jQuery, que o formato é "querystring".
Acredito que se você alterar o contentType para: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` e remover o atributo  `dataType: 'json',`deve funcionar .

Tente assim (Removendo os tributos dataType e contentType o ajax vai usar os valores defaults que é o form-urlencoded):

```
        $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            self.html('<div id="loading"></div>');
        },
        success: function(result) {
            self.html(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            self.html(result.statusText + result.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Ou você precisaria converter a querystring em objeto json antes de atribuí-lo no 'data'.

Comment: Testei dessa forma também e não funcionou. Usei uma função para converter a querystring para json, mas não deu em nada também. Já não faço mais ideia de onde está o problema. Eu tinha "certeza" que era no ajax, mas debuguei e vi que os dados estão sendo enviados e recebidos no laravel, mas quando habilito as rules, me surge o erro 422.

Comment: Já tentou não usar o serialize? Não parece ser ele, ma não custa tentar.
    Por exemplo, volte os atributos <code>dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'</code> e no data passe elemento por elemento: <code>data: {id: $("#id").val(), nome: $("#nome").val() }</code>

Comment: O problema estava no envio em json. Coloquei para enviar normalmente, mantive o serialize e o resto segui da forma que disse e agora está funcionando. Obrigado pela sua ajuda! :)

Comment: Que bom que deu tudo certo Getulio!